# Why isn't absolute deviation used

Tags: standard-deviation, mean-absolute-deviation

If the reason that standard deviation is used is that it's easier to just square the distance every time than find the absolute value. Then why is √(E(x-m)^2)/n not used because if I'm not mistaken |x| = √(x^2) and wouldn't that mean that E|x-m| = √(E(x-m)^2) ?
[image: equation]

Comment: Your "and that would mean" deduction is incorrect.

Comment: I wrote it wrong my bad

Comment: The assertion $E|x-m| = \sqrt{E\left(X-m\right)^2}$ is not correct; you can't pass a square root to the inside of an expected value. This can be seen either by example (with an explicit calculation) or by [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality)